# How to submit two records and assign it to parent using lightning-record-edit-fom

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

Scenario : I have two custom objects

1. Application__c
2. Applicant__c

Application__c is the master object of Applicant__c.
On Application__c object , i have a created a custom picklist field called Applicant_Type__c (picklist values are Single and Joint).

On Application screen if i choose Joint , I have to display two Applicant screens and create two record ids of Applicant on single click.

I am very new to Lightning , please help me out .

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have used the below code to submit the form 

this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-record-edit-form').forEach((form) => {form.submit()});

for lightning-edit-record-form ,we have an attribute called onSuccess ,for this attribute , i am using the event "handleSuccess", in this function 

handleSuccess(event){
    this.applicantId = event.detail.id;
} , 
here i can pass one record id ,

Comment: Can you please add the code that you have tried so far in the question body?